# Showing multiple columns in aggregate function including strings/characters in R

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

R noob question here.

Let's say I have this data frame:

```
City          State Pop
Fresno          CA  494
San Franciso    CA  805
San Jose        CA  945
San Diego       CA  1307
Los Angeles     CA  3792
Reno            NV  225
Henderson       NV  257
Las Vegas       NV  583
Gresham         OR  105
Salem           OR  154
Eugene          OR  156
Portland        OR  583
Fort Worth      TX  741
Austin          TX  790
Dallas          TX  1197
San Antonio     TX  1327
Houston         TX  2100
```

I want to get let's say every 3rd lowest population per State, which would have:

```
City         State  Pop
San Jose        CA  945
Las Vegas       NV  583
Eugene          OR  156
Dallas          TX  1197
```

I tried this one:

```
ord_pop_state <- aggregate(Pop ~ State  , data = ord_pop, function(x) { x[3] } )
```

And I get this one:

```
State  Pop
 CA  945
 NV  583
 OR  156
 TX 1197
```

What do I lack on this one, in order for me to get the desired output that includes the City?

Comment: Btw, this isn't an aggregation operation, rather just subsetting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest to try `data.table` package for such task as the syntax is easier and the code is more efficient. I would also suggest to add `order` function in order to make sure that the data is sorted

```
library(data.table)
setDT(ord_pop)[order(Pop), .SD[3L], keyby = State]
#    State      City  Pop
# 1:    CA  San Jose  945
# 2:    NV Las Vegas  583
# 3:    OR    Eugene  156
# 4:    TX    Dallas 1197
```

So basically, first the data was ordered by `Pop`, then we subsetted `.SD` (which the notation parameter of the data itself) by `State`

---

Though this is easily solvable with base R too (we will assume that the data is sorted here), we can just create an index per group and then just do a simple subset by that index

```
ord_pop$indx <- with(ord_pop, ave(Pop, State, FUN = seq))
ord_pop[ord_pop$indx == 3L, ]
#         City State  Pop indx
# 3   San Jose    CA  945    3
# 8  Las Vegas    NV  583    3
# 11    Eugene    OR  156    3
# 15    Dallas    TX 1197    3
```

Comment: This is a good answer David. But I don't want to use package other than the default that I have. Thanks for your swift answer by the way.

Comment: I provided a bse R alternative... Didn't you see?

Comment: Sorry I did not see that. I'll try that one and come back to you later.

Comment: Thank you David, you got it right. This is basically a subsetting problem. By the way how does ave() works here? Which I understood (if correctly) is for getting the average?

Comment: `ave` has `mean` as its default function but you can override it using the `FUN` argument (just like I did)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `dplyr` version:

```
df2 <- df %>%
    group_by(state) %>% # Group observations by state
    arrange(-pop) %>% # Within those groups, sort in descending order by pop
    slice(3) # Extract the third row in each arranged group
```

Here's the toy data I used to test it:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(state = rep(LETTERS[1:3], each = 5), city = rep(letters[1:5], 3), pop = round(rnorm(15, 1000, 100), digits=0))
```

And here's the output from that; it's a coincidence that 'b' was third-largest in each case, not a glitch in the code:

```
> df2
Source: local data frame [3 x 3]
Groups: state

  state city  pop
1     A    b 1018
2     B    b 1049
3     C    b 1039
```

Comment: Probably `slice(3)` is better than `summarise`

Comment: Right, that will keep the city name, too. Thanks.

Comment: @ulfelder: Thanks for your answer. But I don't want to use dplyr package and just stay with the basic packages for the meantime. What would be my option?

Comment: @DavidArenburg has you covered there.

Answer (score 0):

In R same end results can be achieved using different packages.Choice of package is a trade-off between efficiency and simplicity of code.

Since you come from a strong SQL background,this might be easier to use:

```
library(sqldf)

#Example to return 3rd lowest population of a State
result <-sqldf('Select City,State,Pop from data order by Pop limit 1 offset 2;')

#Note the SQL query is a sample and needs to be modifed to get desired result.
```